# How to determine which test is printing to console

Tags: django, python-unittest

I am trying to figure out which test is printing a datetime warning to console?

I've tried using the '.' notation which I assume is printed after each test, but I am not sure in which order the test seem to be executed. For reference the warning is printed after the first '.' but the second test method in a the first TestCase class is not the culprit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--verbose 2` flag to print file/class/method for each test